# Weird nginx php +cakephp file mixing issue

Tags: cakephp, nginx

On an nginx server i have two virtual hosts
one for ww.domain.com (production)
and another one for test.domain.com - test

The files for the prod server are stored in /var/www/nginx-default and the document root is set to /var/www/nginx-default/app/webroot

The files for the prod server are stored in /var/www/nginx-test and the document root is set to /var/www/nginx-test/app/webroot

the wierd problem is that when i change a few files in the test folder , the output of the prod server changes to include the changes done on the test server
this wierd issue only affects controllers and components file whereas any changes made to views  or to the config folder remain on the designated site.

nginx/0.7.65 ,PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7ppa5~lucid1,apc- 3.1.3p1. Have tried disabling apc but that did not help

what might be causing this mixing of class files?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that you don't have any sym links in these directories

2) Try to run two different php-fpm pools, and use one for production, another for testing

These steps should solve your problem

Comment: I added another pool and pointed the test site to the socket of this pool.Still get the same error. there are no symlinks as such.when i upload 1 file to the test directory and do a nano of the same file in the other directory, i get different files.There is no logical reason for the files to be shared

Comment: The solution to this was to change the cache engine in core.php to file